# Does anyone have information about the nj32disk.sys driver?

Tags: ms-dos, emulation, hard-disk, driver

I'm currently trying to use the nj32disk.sys driver to use my USB stick as a virtual hard drive. The problem is that the driver acts like a floppy disk. My question is: Is there a documentation about nj32disk.sys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a [short text file describing `NJ32DISK.SYS`](https://www.jumpjet.info/Application-Software/DOS/Hardware/3/NJ32DISK/About.txt), but it doesn’t say much:

> NJ32DISK.SYS is the ASPI disk driver for USB mass-storage devices (it
> assigns a DOS drive letter). Run the USB hardware driver (such as
> USBASPI.SYS) before NJ32DISK (similar to the way you first run the
> cd-rom ASPI driver before running MSCDEX).  If USBASPI does not find
> any USB mass-storage devices on bootup, NJ32DISK will not load or
> assign any drive letters.  Drive letters assigned will come after the
> internal Floppy drive, Hard drive, and other bios established storage
> devices have been assigned drive letters.
>
> This driver will assign its USB drive letters before the CD/DVD gets
> assigned their drive letters (due to NJ32DISK being loaded in
> Config.sys wheras the CD/DVD MSCDEX driver is loaded in Autoexec.bat).
> Therefore to keep your CD/DVD drive letters consistant, it is suggested
> that you always boot with the USB mass-storage devices connected, or
> that you assign a "starting" drive letter to your CD/DVD unit that
> appears lower in the alphabet than the USB assigned drive letter.
>
> After a drive letter has been assigned, you can remove and replace the
> mass-storage media (of the same formatted Mb size) in a similar fashion
> as you can remove and replace floppy diskettes (the cache may have to
> be refreshed to recognize the media change though, just as you must
> often do with floppy diskettes).

You might be better off looking at [Bret Johnson’s USB drivers](http://bretjohnson.us/), they’re documented and quite configurable.